# Stop key is pressed or send key event only when the key itself is held down

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

How would I always stop SendInput and ControlSend for DOWN key is pressed when the DOWN key is not held down any longer?

```
~Down::
SendInput {Down down}
ControlSend,, {Down down}
Return
```

Edit: OK this, but it's kinda slow:

```
Down::
SendInput {Down down}
ControlSend,, {Down down}
return
Down Up::
SendInput {Down up}
ControlSend,, {Down up}
Return
```

I already see that a While loop works much faster, but it's not working properly by 100% yet.
How would I wrap my code above into a While loop routine effectively?

Edit2: Defining one key in a While loop is working properly:

```
Down::
While GetKeyState("Down", "P")
{
SendInput, {Down down}
ControlSend,, {Down down}
}
SendInput, {Down Up}
ControlSend,, {Down Up}
Return
```

Edit3: Defining multiple keys is buggy - this is also not working properly:

```
$Down::
$Left::
$Right::
SendInput, % "{" . LTrim(A_ThisHotkey, "$") . " Down}"
KeyWait, % LTrim(A_ThisHotkey, "$")
SendInput, % "{" . LTrim(A_ThisHotkey, "$") . " Up}"
Return
```

Comment: I can't create this rule?: When DOWN key pressed: Send and ControlSend Key DOWN is down. When DOWN key not pressed: Send and ControlSend Key DOWN is up.
That's all I need to know.

Comment: Try the [while loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/While.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This work?

```
    $down::
    sendinput {down down}
    controlsend,,{down down}
    while (getkeystate("down","p")){
        sleep 20
    }
    sendinput {down up}
    controlsend,,{down up}
    return
```